# Wowza Media Streaming API

Tags: php, xml, curl, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am php Developer and i tried so many ways to get this xml through php-curl process.but haven't found proper solution so could you please let me know how do i call API in php such as on-demand video, audio,and IP-Cemera API directly through PHP Script.

I have also tried HTTP provider but unable to call wowza's API directly.

Thank you
"Have a nice day ahead"

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write java to add server side functionality in  Wowza. You can use any IDE but they provide an Eclipse plugin; More info here : http://www.wowza.com/streaming/developers.

Comment: Thank's for your reply is there any way to make wowza apis thourgh php. i want to make webservices using php but i have readout there is no option to get all wowza apis through php.

Comment: Correct, the only built-in http providers, which you could access from a php app, are http://[wowza-ip-address]:8086/serverinfo,
http://[wowza-ip-address]:8086/connectioncounts,
http://[wowza-ip-address]:8086/connectioninfo.  Anything more and you'll have to write your own in Java, then you can use them from php.